# Matrix Contour Plot of 3 Parameters

Tags: python, plot, contour, contourf, data-representation

I have run an MCMC chain for parameter estimation and have obtained accepted parameter values. I have 3 parameters and about 300 000 accepted values for each parameter.

I would now like to do a contour plot (doable) but in a 3-choose-2 triangular matrix type (a very specific requirement) Please see the attached photo [contour-plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghi6f.png). The image shows some unrelated contour-plots from a paper but I want to have a similar type of plot for my parameters.

In total, I will have 6 plots: 3 single parameter histograms (like the top plot in each column in the image) and 3-choose-2 = 3 contour plots (as the lower triangle). Again, I need it to look as much as possible like the image.

How to achieve this on Python?

**Update:**

I have been able to write the below code which gives me a plot as [my-plot-here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1aOC.png).

However, I need an exact / as best as possible match with the type of figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghi6f.png). i.e. I need my xticks, yticks to show inside and not outside, the spaces between the figues to go away, a better way to show the left vertical plot labels (I'm currently using set_ylabel), the outer crooked contour level to go away, and have detailed (long-short) ticks along the x-axis of the pdfs.

```
def plot_histogram_fig(param, nbins, subplot_index, subplot_title):
    counts, bins = np.histogram(param, bins = nbins)
    plotcounts = np.insert(counts, -1, counts[-1])
    bincentres = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, subplot_index)
    #ax.step(bins, plotcounts, where='post', c='y')
    ax.plot(bincentres, counts, 'b')
    #ax.plot([bins[np.argmax(counts)], bins[np.argmax(counts)]], [0, np.max(counts)], 'y')
    ax.set_yticks([])
    return [ax, counts, bincentres]

def plot_contour_fig(p1, p2, nbins, subplot_index):
    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(p1, p2, bins = nbins)
    Z = H.T
    #Z_gauss = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(Z, sigma = 0.8, order = 0) #filtering
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1], yedges[:-1])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, subplot_index)
    im = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels = 6)
    #plt.colorbar(im, ax = ax)
    ax.clabel(im, inline=True, fontsize=4)
    return [ax, H, xedges, yedges]

nbins = 50

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))

#Histograms

ax1 = plot_histogram_fig(all_alphas, nbins, 1, subplot_title = 'alpha')
ax1[0].set_xticks([])
ax1[0].set_ylabel('alpha')

ax5 = plot_histogram_fig(all_betas, nbins, 5, subplot_title = 'beta')
ax5[0].set_xticks([])

ax9 = plot_histogram_fig(all_gammas, nbins, 9, subplot_title = 'gamma')
ax9[0].set_title('gamma', y = -0.5)

#Contours

ax4 = plot_contour_fig(all_alphas, all_betas, nbins, 4)
ax4[0].set_xticklabels([])
ax4[0].set_ylabel('beta')

ax7 = plot_contour_fig(all_alphas, all_gammas, nbins, 7)
ax7[0].set_title('alpha', y = -0.5)
ax7[0].set_ylabel('gamma')

ax8 = plot_contour_fig(all_betas, all_gammas, nbins, 8)
ax8[0].set_yticklabels([])
ax8[0].set_title('beta', y = -0.5)

plt.show()
```

all_alphas, all_betas, all_gammas are 1d numpy arrays storing the accepted parameter values.

Comment: We can only help you if you provide us with an example of what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I haven't been able to think of a way of achieving this. I believe I can create a (3x3) subplot (using fig.add_subplot()) and plot the figures individually by creating axes with (1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9) indices in figure but however, that will preserve the individual x, y axis for each figure and not join them as in the image. However, since you mentioned, I will (very soon) edit the post and add a code for what I currently said. Thanks for letting me know, I am new here.

Comment: Hi, I have included a code and a plot, kindly take a look! Thanks!